# EhCache DiskStore is in memory

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jvm, ehcache

I use EhCache with a memory cache loaded from a disk cache.

When dumping the JVM of my process, I noticed that EhCache stored in memory the cache **and** the diskstore object of that cache.

The memory size of both is getting big (DiskStore in memory is around 75% of the memory cache).

I am wondering why the DiskStore is on disk **and** in memory, in addition to the normal memory cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cache caches data in memory for speed of access. You have to load the data into memory to use it and it is a very bad idea to remove it from disk just because its in memory.

Saving disks resources is a waste of time in this case as disk space is relative cheap and changing it is relatively expensive.

Comment: "it is a very bad idea to remove it from disk" : I don't remove anything from the disk. I have, in memory, the normal cache loaded from the disk, and a "DiskStore" object that takes up u lot of memory too. It seems that there is, in memory, both the memory cache and the disk cache...

Comment: @Mattieu, I imagine the Diskstore has the serialized form of the records.  But I agree than two copies in memory is wasteful.